# Remote Host closed connection during hansdshake while connecting to ISA server from SOAP UI

Tags: java, soap, soapui, soap-client, netweaver

We are trying to connect to ISA server over HTTPS from SOAP UI client. The ISA server redirects the URL to the required windows server within the organization.

When u send a request from SOAP UI client, we get "Remote host closed connection during handshake" error.

We have not changed any parameters on SOAP UI client or as read in few other blogs have not imported any certificates. Is importing certificate mandatory?

How do we go about to get succesful connection.

-Anand

Comment: ISA server is the organization firewall, where tranlation rule for redirection is written.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. The cretificate on ISA server was not deployed properly. The network admin team re-depolyed the certificates and the rule works fine.